# setting up ssl for cname only subdomain

Tags: ssl, subdomain, cname-record

I've looked on for an answer on google and other forums for this question but couldn't get a solution or a hint for the scenario that I have.

I've a domain, say abc.com, which is live with ssl on wpengine. Now we need to show a third party login form on our own subdomain, [you can read the 3rd party requirement for this setup here](https://help.officernd.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002216394-Custom-Domain-for-Members-Portal).

Now, say I need to show that 3rd party login on my own subdomain according to their steps on portal.abc.com, and the main requirement of that third party is that the subdomain must have ssl(for which we need to provide them files also) and the subdomain must then cname there domain.

The thing I can't figure out yet is how the ssl will be applied to the cname only subdomain?

Any hints or suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: You don't configure the SSL certificate, you just buy the SSL cert and send it to the vendor.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement correctly, you are looking for wildcard certificate one good reference https://www.godaddy.com/help/what-is-a-wildcard-ssl-certificate-567